# Memory management in C++.

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have the following program:

```
//simple array memory test.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void someFunc(float*, int, int);

int main() {

  int convert = 2;

  float *arr = new float[17];
  for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    arr[i] = 1.0;
  }

  someFunc(arr, 17, convert);

  for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}

void someFunc(float *arr, int num, int flag) {

  if(flag) {
    delete []arr;
  }
}
```

When I put the following into `gdb` and insert a break point at `float *arr ...`, I step through the program and observe the following:

1. Printing the array `arr` after it has been initialized gives me 1 17 times.
2. Inside `someFunc` too, I print `arr` before `delete` to get the same print as above.
3. Upon going back into `main`, when I print `arr`, I get the first digit as 0 followed by 16 1.0s.

My questions:
1. Once the array has been deleted in `someFunc`, how am I still able to access `arr` without a segfault in `someFunc` or `main`?
2. The code snippet above is a test version of another piece of code that runs in a bigger program. I observe the same behaviour in both places (first digit is `0` but all others are the same. If this is some unexplained memory error, how am I observing the same thing in different areas?
3. Some explanations to fill the gaps in my understanding are most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A segfault occurs when you access a memory address that isn't mapped into the process. Calling `delete []` releases memory back to the memory allocator, but usually not to the OS.

The contents of the memory after calling `delete []` are an implementation detail that varies across compilers, libraries, OSes and especially debug-vs-release builds. Debug memory allocators, for instance, will often fill the memory with some tell-tale signature like 0xdeadbeef.

Comment: Or at least not immediatly - there is caches which behave differently depending on the memory-'situation' of your system.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a pointer after it has been `delete`ed is undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Once the array has been deleted, any access to it is undefined behavior.
There's no guarantee that you'll get a segment violation; in fact,
typically you won't.  But there's no guarantee of what you will get; in
larger programs, modifying the contents of the array could easily result
in memory corruption elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` gives the memory back to the OS memory manager, but does not necessarily clears the contents in the memory(it should not, as it causes overhead for nothing). So the values are retained in the memory. And in your case, you are accessing the same memory -- so it will print what is in the memory -- it is not necessarily an undefined behaviour(depends on memory manager)

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior. It is specified as such in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Re 1: You can't. If you want to access arr later, don't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't check for array boundaries. Only if you access a memory which you  are not allowed to you  will get segfault